# How can I solve problem logout on safari browser? (auth nuxt)

Tags: vue.js, authentication, vuejs2, nuxt.js

When I log out in Chrome and Firefox browser it works fine. But when I logged out on safari, it didn't go well. When I click logout, it goes to the login page then returns to the home page. After I click logout one more time. It made it to the login page. So I have to click logout twice on safari browser

My code like this  :

```
async logout () {
    await this.$auth.logout()
    this.SET_IS_AUTH(false)
    // this.$router.push('/')
    window.location.href = '/'
}
```

My auth in nuxt.config.js like this :

```
auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/',
      home: '/home',
      logout: '/'
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        scheme: 'refresh',
        token: {
          property: 'response.token',
          // maxAge: 3600,
          // type: 'Bearer'
        },
        refreshToken: {
          property: 'response.token',
          // data: 'refresh_token',
          // maxAge: 60 * 60
        },
        endpoints: {
          login: {
            url: '/auth/token',
            method: 'post',
            propertyName: 'response.token'
          },
          user: false,
          logout: false
        },
        tokenRequired: true,
        tokenType: 'Bearer '
      }
    },
    token: {
      name: 'token'
    },
    cookie: {
      name: 'token'
    }
},
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why you exit the app by `window.location.href = '/'` ?

Comment: @Raffobaffo I read in some reference. And they say to do that